# AutoBean complex JSON parse

Tags: json, gwt, autobean

I have a complex JSON String and i try to parse it using AutoBean.

The JSON String looks like :

```
 `{
 "status": "OK",
 "result": {
  "geometry": [
   [
    {
     "X": 268347.4,
     "Y": 6743983.1
    },
    {
     "X": 268341.1,
     "Y": 6743989.7
    }
   ],
   [
    {
     "X": 268378.15,
     "Y": 6743972.7
    },
    {
     "X": 268347.4,
     "Y": 6743983.1
    }
   ]
  ]
 }
}`
```

I have created this interface

```
public interface BrancheAutoBean {

  String getResult();
  GeometryModel getGeometryModel()
}

public interface GeometryModel {
  @PropertyName("geometry")
    List<Geometry> getGeometry();
}

public interface Geometry{

  @PropertyName("X")
   Double getX();

  @PropertyName("Y")
   Double getY();
}
```

How can I make it work? And how to add the X and Y array to the geomtry
i found some example like adding the X and Y when parsing the bean:

```
Geometry bean =AutoBeanCodex.decode(factory, GeometryModel.class, "{\"Geometry\": " + strResponse + "}").as();
```

but my application must implement générique parsing.
thanx in advence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BrancheAutoBean` are either misnamed or lacking `@PropertyName` annotations: *result* should be *status*, and *geometryModel* should be *result*.

Then, your `GeometryModel`'s `getGeometry` should be a `List<List<Geometry>>`. I'm not sure this is supported by AutoBean though.